# Is it plus or minus of parallel programming?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

Here is some question:

C#, Parallel.For, or Parallel.ForEach...

Does it make sense to code parallel cycle inside another one?

Does it slow program? What about productivity?

What I am really interested in is ... if the first loop is doing "light" part of code instead main part is inside second loop is it better just leave second loop and transform first loop into simple foreach?

example =>

```
Parallel.ForEach(sourse,action=>{
  //to do smt very fast

Parallel.ForEach(sourse2,action2=>{

       //here is main code of program,
      // where there is lot of http requests and etc...
 });

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should also read [this](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: It depends on many factors, so measure in (close to) the real context.

Answer (score 1):

No, it makes no sense to do this. You should strive to invoke your parallelism as high up the chain as possible, in order to get the most efficient usage of threads.

As `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` by default try to partition the work automatically based on the number of available cores, having two partitioners fighting over available cores would very likely slow down their work.

Comment: You should elaborate on _to get the most efficient usage of threads_, specifically why OP's approach is inefficient.

Comment: This is old advice. I've tried a few scenarios and it never degrades much. And in some cases (large body of work in inner loop) it speeds things up.